# When installing Rust toolchain in Docker, Bash `source` command doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am trying to create a docker image that will setup a Linux environment for building Rust projects.  Here is my `Dockerfile` so far:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update default packages
RUN apt-get update

# Get Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl

# Update new packages
RUN apt-get update

# Get Rust
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y
```

The last thing I need to do is configure Rust, so that I can use `cargo`.  The documentation says to use

```
source $HOME/.cargo/env
```

but when I try that in a `RUN` command in a Dockerfile, it says `source` is not recognized.  Another option I found was to use

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.cargo/env"
```

This does not error, but when I run my container, `cargo` is not a recognized command.

Either approach works from Bash when I have the container open, but I would like this to be automated as part of the image.

How can I integrate this into my Dockerfile?

Comment: `bash -c 'source anything'` only `source`s a file *into that single `bash` instance*, which exits when the command completes. The right way to use it is `bash -c 'source ~/.cargo/env && cargo whatever'`, running the `source` in the same shell that actually needs to use what you're adding.

Comment: (also, consider `.` instead of `source` -- the latter name is a bashism, whereas the former is POSIX-mandated).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to add the sourcing inside the .bashrc.

This works:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update default packages
RUN apt-get update

# Get Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl

# Update new packages
RUN apt-get update

# Get Rust
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y

RUN echo 'source $HOME/.cargo/env' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

EDIT

Instead of

`RUN echo 'source $HOME/.cargo/env' >> $HOME/.bashrc`

you can use

`ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"`

which is a less bash-only solution

Comment: `.bashrc` is not honored by (all) noninteractive shells. It's thus not a particularly appropriate option for this use case.

Comment: I am aware of that, I answered like that because it seemed to me that that was what he was trying to do: use an interactive bash inside the docker container and having cargo commands available

Comment: You can go with `ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"`, it's a good and transparent way of making `cargo` visible. 

P.S. note `/root` in my example, you can build as root via `USER root` in dockerfile, or you can change `/root` to desired dir.

Comment: The solution with `ENV PATH=...` seems to generally work better with most docker images

Comment: if you don't mind, can you explain how does `bash -s -- -y` work exactly. The command worked, but I don't understand how it choose the first option form the prompt ? Does the shell file downloaded from the url accept `-y` as a parameter ? If so, how did you find that, it's not written anywhere on the download page. I am very lost here

Comment: This is not my command, it is (actually it was) in their documentation.
From what I understand, the `-s` allows the arguments to be read from the standard input. the `--` could be something understood by the script to pass the arguments after to the underlying script. 
Like when you want to launch ignored tests in rust with `cargo test -- --ignored`

Comment: `-s` means operate silently. `--` is used to separate the options passed to sh from the positional parameters that follow. `-y` - is a positional parameter passed to the script executed by sh - here rust script.

Answer (score 39):

The only thing `source ~/.cargo/env` does is

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

So my suggestion is to set PATH explicitly in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update default packages
RUN apt-get -qq update

# Get Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get install -y -q \
    build-essential \
    curl

# NOTE: no need to run update again at this point
# RUN apt-get update

# Get Rust; NOTE: using sh for better compatibility with other base images
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

# Add .cargo/bin to PATH
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

# Check cargo is visible
RUN cargo --help
```

This is slightly more transparent than `source .cargo/env`, and easier to grasp if you're not familiar with Rust.

Also, note that there are [rust](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/rustlang/rust) on DockerHub, you can use them (in `FROM`, instead of `ubuntu:16.04`) for running  or building Rust apps. It will be faster and easier than installing everything via apt and curl.

For building apps there's a possibility you will find [multistage docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) useful. They are [pretty flexible](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae).

Comment: One more option is to replace `ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"` with `SHELL [ "/bin/sh", "-s", ".", "$HOME/.cargo/env" ]` which prepends the source to each command after this.

Comment: Wow, interesting! Why do that, what's the pro? @blanNL

Comment: This does not seem to work.  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in my container, and it can't find cargo (RUN cargo --help fails)

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be misunderstanding what `source` does. This built-in command tells the current shell to load the following code (almost) as if it were being run at the current prompt (you can also use source inside other scripts). It's basically an "include file here" command.  It's mostly used to set up your environment (PATH, LIBPATH, and other shell functions), not to do real work.

Running "source" in a RUN command is thus (almost always) useless. It will load up the cargo environment and then exit, thus losing all the environment changes.

This leaves you with two basic options. One is to do as michael_bitard suggests, and get it added to your `.bashrc`. This will mean that all commands forevermore in that container (by that user) will have the environment set up. If you only need this for setup, then it pollutes your shell environment at runtime.

The second option is to basically run the source as part of every RUN command that needs it in the rest of your `Dockerfile`.  `RUN bash -c 'source $HOME/.cargo/env; command goes here` for example. This is more work on each RUN line, but the environment will be explicitly there when you need it, and not when you don't.

*Most of the time*, the first option is what you want.  *Rarely* you want the second. That is, sometimes you only need this environment for setup purposes, and you don't want it to persist - this is rare, though I've had that scenario come up a few times.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not understand the nature of `source` at all.  I am very new to Bash and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`source` (or `.`) is a shell built in command - it runs the commands from the file given as parameter in the current shell. This is useful for configuring your current environment (aliases, functions and environment variables) configured in a script does not apply to the parent shell that started it, with `source` those can be configured. This is why `RUN` fails - there is no executable called `source`. (It might work with the shell form of `RUN` or with `SHELL`)

To run a command with items set up from that file, you should be able to get away with:

```
RUN bash -c 'source ~/.cargo/env; cargo <whatever>'
```

If you want the variables to be applied to a shell inside the container, you need to add the source command to one of the bash files that is sourced when the shell is started, e.g. `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (depending on whether a login shell is started or not) or (on most distributions) a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d/`

One way to do this would be the following in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN ln -s $HOME/.cargo/env /etc/profile.d/cargo_env.sh
```