# Error in pip install transformers: Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, docker

I'm building a docker image on cloud server via the following docker file:

```
# base image
FROM python:3

# add python file to working directory
ADD ./ /

# install and cache dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install RUST
RUN pip install transformers
RUN pip install torch
RUN pip install slack_sdk
RUN pip install slack_bolt
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install gensim
RUN pip install nltk
RUN pip install psycopg2
RUN pip install openpyxl
......
```

When installing the transformers package, the following error occurs:

```
STEP 5: RUN pip install transformers
Collecting transformers
  Downloading transformers-4.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)
Collecting filelock
  ......
  Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tokenizers
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml): started
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp_3y7hw5q
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bsy5f4da/tokenizers_e09b9f903acd40f0af4a997fe1d8fdb4
  Complete output (50 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  ......
  copying py_src/tokenizers/trainers/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/tokenizers/trainers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/tools/visualizer-styles.css -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/tokenizers/tools
  running build_ext
  error: can't find Rust compiler
  
  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.
  
  To update pip, run:
  
      pip install --upgrade pip
  
  and then retry package installation.
  
  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build tokenizers
subprocess exited with status 1
subprocess exited with status 1
error building at STEP "RUN pip install transformers": exit status 1
time="2022-01-18T07:24:56Z" level=error msg="exit status 1"
Dockerfile build failed - exit status 1exit status 1
```

I'm not very sure about what's happening here. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try putting all you requirements into a `req.txt` file and then `RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r req.txt`. Note the `&&`. The prob is, if that works I can't tell why -.- but I had a similar issue.

Comment: @deponovo Thanks a lot. If you have similar issue, maybe you can have a look at the following answer:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logs say

```
error: can't find Rust compiler
```

You need to install a rust compiler. See https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install. You can modify the installation instructions for a docker image like this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169817/5666087):

```
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution helps. BTW, I changed the python version to python3.8 and the installation was successful too.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked. Thanks very very much. Spent an hour trying to fix this

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue for me. I'm still seeing "error: can't find Rust compiler" even though `rustc` is in my PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a clean python=3.8 environment and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try version 4.16 of transformers, I had the same error with version 4.15

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, there is an already accepted answer. Please follow the advice in above comment.