# ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers

Tags: python, pip

I am using Windows 11 x64, Python 3.11.0 run

```
pip install transformers
```

error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.674]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

C:\Users\donhu>conda install -c huggingface transformers
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\donhu>pip install transformers
Collecting transformers
  Downloading transformers-4.24.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.5 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 5.5/5.5 MB 12.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting filelock
  Using cached filelock-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.10.0
  Using cached huggingface_hub-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (21.3)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (143 kB)
Collecting regex!=2019.12.17
  Using cached regex-2022.10.31-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (267 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from transformers) (2.28.1)
Collecting tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.14,>=0.11.1
  Downloading tokenizers-0.13.1.tar.gz (358 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 358.7/358.7 kB 21.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting tqdm>=4.27
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=20.0->transformers) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.27->transformers) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\donhu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2022.9.24)
Building wheels for collected packages: tokenizers
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [51 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\models
      copying py_src\tokenizers\models\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\models
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\decoders
      copying py_src\tokenizers\decoders\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\decoders
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\normalizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\normalizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\normalizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\processors
      copying py_src\tokenizers\processors\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\processors
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\trainers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\trainers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\trainers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\base_tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\bert_wordpiece.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\byte_level_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\char_level_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\sentencepiece_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\sentencepiece_unigram.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\implementations
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\tools
      copying py_src\tokenizers\tools\visualizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\tools
      copying py_src\tokenizers\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\tools
      copying py_src\tokenizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\models\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\models
      copying py_src\tokenizers\decoders\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\decoders
      copying py_src\tokenizers\normalizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\normalizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\processors\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\processors
      copying py_src\tokenizers\trainers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\trainers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\tools\visualizer-styles.css -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tokenizers\tools
      running build_ext
      running build_rust
      error: can't find Rust compiler

      If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

      To update pip, run:

          pip install --upgrade pip

      and then retry package installation.

      If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\Users\donhu>
```

[image]
How to fix it?

Comment: `error: can't find Rust compiler` is the root cause. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70758728/245915 ?

Answer (score 1):

should install rust first.

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`  from [link](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)