# could not install specified verison of Transformers

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

i am trying to install transformers==4.10.3 in colab and iam getting the following error

```
equirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacremoses->transformers==3.03.0) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacremoses->transformers==3.03.0) (8.1.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: tokenizers
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

i tried installing locally it worked fine i tried uninstalling the transformers library then re installing it with specified version but nothing worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in pip install transformers: Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751892/error-in-pip-install-transformers-building-wheel-for-tokenizers-pyproject-toml)